# How to increment a value inside a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list called `quan = [0, 0 ,0, 0]`. I'm asking the user to input integers between 0 to 3 and storing them in another list called items. eg: `items = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.
For each int in items, I want to increment the corresponding position in quan, i.e., quan should become `[1, 2, 3, 0]` in this case.

```
for i in items:
    quan[items[i]] += 1
```

so far all I've ended up with an EoL error. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: just do `quan[i] += 1`. `i` contains the element, not the index so you can access it directly using `quan[i]`.

Comment: I don't see a reason for End of Line error.

Answer (score 2):

For the question as asked:

```
quan = [0, 0, 0, 0]
items = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

for i in items:
    quan[i] += 1
```

In most real situations, though, you probably want to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead, which provides the same answer in slightly different form:

```
from collections import Counter

items = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
quan = Counter(items)
```

Comment: Counter does not maintain the right item order, so this is probably not a useful alternative.

Comment: Yeah; that's why I provided the "as asked" answer. In most real situations, though, either the item order is irrelevant or the Counter can be scanned in order; either way, using a library function is usually better than writing code.

Comment: The question goes *"the user provides a list of positions to increment, and then I want to increment those positions"*, so the position of the element is kind of important. `Counter` does something entirely different. (Not to mention that `quan` is probably not always all zero at the start.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
for i in items:
    quan[i]+=1
```

The EOL might be caused by a typo somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Below code loop will iterate only 4 times rather than no. of elements in items' list.
count() of the list will return no. of occurrences of that element.

```
quan = [0, 0, 0, 0]
items = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]


for i in range(4):
    quan[i] += items.count(i)

print(quan)
```

or alternatively

```
quan = [quan[i]+items.count(i) for i in range(4)]
```